# Using variable in default filter in Ansible Jinja2 template

Tags: ansible

Inside a an Ansible Jinja2 template I'm trying to set a "default" value which also has a variable in it but it's printing out the literal rather than interpolating it.

For example:

```
homedir = {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['instances'][app_instance]['homedir'] | default("/home/{{ app_instance }}/airflow") }}
```

returns:

```
airflow_home = /home/{{ app_instance }}/airflow
```

How to refer to the `app_instance` variable?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Inside Jinja2 expression use Jinja2 syntax. You should concatenate strings to a variable value:

```
homedir = {{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['instances'][app_instance]['homedir'] | default("/home/" + app_instance + "/airflow") }}
```